# plugin_customization.ini

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Whenever I launch the .product of an rcp application , some values from my plugin_customization.ini are erased .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not getting overwritten by some other process?

AFAIK, the plugin_customization.ini file is read only.

Comment: do not have a clue what is happening to it